# Need advice for Oracle SQL SUM aggregate function between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate

I have two tables in an Oracle database that I am trying to form a SELECT statement from. 
The first table is called "Donations" and contains the following attributes: 
donation_id, 
donation_date, 
donor_id, 
donation_type    (there are 2 options for type: 'Incoming' or 'Outgoing')

The second table, an intersection table, is called "donation_item" and has these attributes:
item_id,
donation_id,
location_id,
weight

The donation_type, item_id, and weight columns are the ones which  I am particularly interested in. My objective is to use an aggregate function (SUM) to add the weights of a certain item_id of a particular donation_type ('Incoming') and then from that answer, subtract the weight of the same item_id of the 'Outgoing' donation_type items.

I have tried several queries and all have produced errors. I'm not sure if the objective is possible given the current structure of the tables. An example of code that was tried is as follows:

```
SELECT SUM(i.weight) - SUM(o.weight) AS "Total"
FROM donation_item i JOIN donation_item o
ON i.item_id = o.item_id JOIN donations d
ON i.donation_id = d.donation_id 
WHERE i.donation_type <> o.donation_type
AND i.donation_type = 'Incoming';
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
SELECT
    DONATION_ITEMS.ITEM_ID,
    SUM
    (
        CASE DONATIONS.DONATION_TYPE
            WHEN 'Incoming' THEN 1
            WHEN 'Outgoing' THEN -1
        END
        *
        DONATION_ITEMS.WEIGHT
    )
FROM
    DONATIONS
    INNER JOIN
    DONATION_ITEMS
    ON
    DONATIONS.DONATION_ID = DONATION_ITEMS.DONATION_ID
GROUP BY
    DONATION_ITEMS.ITEM_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
sum(i.weight - o.weight)
```